# What is a "listed natural gas appliance"?

Tags: united-states, regulations, colorado

My landlord mentioned that I can have a grill on my balcony as long as it is fueled by natural gas. As he is a fireman, I'm assuming he has some knowledge of the relevant laws.

But before dropping several hundred dollars on a new grill, I wanted to make sure, so I am looking at [BARBECUES, PROPANE AND HEAT-PRODUCING DEVICES ON BALCONIES](https://www.denvergov.org/content/dam/denvergov/Portals/678/documents/Barbeques%20on%20Balconies%20-%20Mgrs%20and%20owners%20of%20multi-family%20dwellings%2012-11-12.pdf) from the Denver Fire Department, and at the end it reads

> Exceptions:
>   ...
>   3.Listed natural gas appliances...
>   4.Listed electric ranges, grills or similar electrical apparatus...

What does "listed" mean in this context? The document has no list. But my natural gas appliance is listed on Amazon's, Lowe's, and Home Depot's websites. I assume that's not what the document means.

Comment: I think they mean the product has been tested and certified safe.

Comment: You are going to have to ask the fire department if you want an authoritative answer.  I am pretty sure Putvi's guess is right (UL has historically used the term "listed" to describe products it has certified as meeting its safety standards), but I don't see any way that anyone here can prove it to you.

Comment: @NateEldredge I agree that's the most likely case and if Putvi's answer is the best I'll accept it, but I'm hoping someone might pipe in here with a decree from England in 1349 that states "and hereby 'listed' shall mean UL and not ETL" or something like that. Really this is a question about expanding my familiarity with legalese and what I can and cannot assume.

Comment: I agree with @Nate Eldredge. But I will mention that when I lived in an apartment with a balcony in NJ, we were told "absolutely no grills using bottled gas" on the balcony or in the apt because of fire danger, and later there was a fire which totally destroyed a group of eight apartments which was reportedly due to such a grill.

Comment: @DavidSiegel That has been my experience as well (the prohibition, not the fire) which is why my landlord's passing remark caught me off guard.

Comment: You realize they didn't have UL in those days right?

Comment: @Putvi A poor attempt at humor on my part :)

Comment: I know, I'm not knocking it. I like humor. I just meant that being that there literally is no other definition of listed for an appliance, it may confuse people.

Comment: @Putvi I am not a lawyer, and this is a place for laymen asking questions about the law, so I think "is 'listed' a term with specific legal meaning" is perfectly valid.

Comment: I didn't mean to say that it doesn't have a meaning, but just that it's not something that has a meaning that could differ in the same way as some legal things like what is fair use in copyrights so if someone came across this they may say to themselves oh I thought everyone agreed it meant safety listed with UL or a similar place and it would throw them off. I might be wrong about others thinking it, but if I saw that pop up on Google that is what I would think personally. I am not knocking your question though.

Comment: @Putvi I think that would make an excellent edit to your answer (which I already upvoted and will presumably accept in a few days) to add context. Something like "Some terms are generally accepted as obvious without a strict definition or precedent. If there were an edge case, precedent would need to be set but it hasn't happened yet".

Comment: Good idea @Turch.

Comment: Not a lawyer, nor a PE, but my understanding from designing electronic devices that needed pass various certification requirements is that UL and ETL are legally equivalent. Both are "Nationally Recognized Testing Labs" (NRTLs) and a mark from one is legally just as good as a mark from the other.

Comment: The actual ordinance says "Listed natural gas appliances shall be permitted on balconies when installed in accordance with the International Fuel Gas Code...", which also specifically defines "listed". It is identical to the paragraph quoted in @Mark's answer copied from the IFC.  End of story.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am not from Denver, so it may be different there, but I would think most people would take that to mean the appliance meets UL standards or other safety standards and has been certified.

Each governing body, be it a town, county, state, or country, gets to decide who can certify an appliance.

Comment: That's what I assume as well, but as far as I know the law doesn't work on "I thought I was allowed", which is why I'm clarifying.

Comment: I understand. I just don't think there's room for that to be anything else.

Comment: So, to legally have my homemade grill on my balcony, am I allowed to certify it myself or do I have to form a corporation? (which would probably be a good idea anyway to protect myself from the future lawsuits from the fire caused by my poorly designed grill) This comment was frivolous at first but after thinking about it, as a diy/tinkerer that likes welding and metalwork, maybe someday I *would* be interested in making a homemade grill. Would having that on my balcony be legal? (And as for the corporation part, as far as I know UL is just a corporation with no government oversight)

Comment: No, it wouldn't be legal because you admit you didn't have it listed, obviously. I am not the UL people, but they would access your grill and tell you it was good or what to improve. It would just go on a case by case basis.

Comment: What I am asking is, UL is a corporation (not a government entity) that "certifies" things. What prevents me from starting a corporation with my own standards and certifications? Obviously if something my company certified turned out to be faulty, my company would be liable (which is the same thing that would happen to UL). But, *until* the failure, is there a legal difference between getting my hypothetical grill certified by UL and my own corporation?

Comment: In other words, is there any other requirement to "listing" other than some entity saying "I declare this is safe, and will be responsible for any damages if it is not"?

Comment: You could start your own company to certify things. There are others out there. It's just that UL's standards are agreed to be good by most governments around the world, not just here in the US and your company would not have the same standing at first.

Comment: @Turch to be broadly accepted you'd need to get your testing company nationally recognized or convince your specific locality to accept your work as being equivalent (good luck). UL is just by a large margin the best known in the USA.  (The only other one on the list I recognized was TÜV, and only because of a project where we needed to meet German compliance standards.)  https://www.osha.gov/dts/otpca/nrtl/nrtllist.html

Comment: @DanNeely That makes sense. If I'm understanding correctly: If it's on OSHA's list it will be accepted at any local level, otherwise if the local government recognizes it (whether via an official list or unofficial "that's what we've always done" list). Is that correct?

Comment: The local government has the right to make their own list, and other countries do as well. He is saying that UL is already accepted by all those entities. Like if you made your own testing lab, Denver could say no to you even if OSHA said yes or another country said yes.

Comment: Ah, so if a certification company is and OSHA "NRTL", it doesn't necessarily mean that Denver will accept it? In that case, how do I find out if "Bay Area Compliance Laboratories" (an OSHA NRTL) is accepted by Denver?

Comment: You would have to ask Denver, honestly, but I have never heard of a city not honoring a company certified by OSHA. Normally, you would just assume that it would apply, unless the city told you otherwise, but I meant the city has that right.

Comment: @Putvi Ok, that's exactly what my comment was trying to clarify. Thanks for the extended explanations!

Comment: I'm glad it helped if it did.

Comment: @DanNeely Actually NRTL is irrelevant in this case. NRTL is run by OSHA and as a result, OSHA only supervises under a limited set of [occupational safety standards](https://www.osha.gov/dts/otpca/nrtl/list_standards.html). Many home appliances do not fall under OSHA's occupational safety purview, and test labs therefore cannot become NRTLs. For example, [this fireplace](http://superiorfireplaces.us.com/system/document_files/files/000/000/131/original/127014-01_B_Superior_WRE4800_Outdoor_Wood-Burning_Fireplaces__IICO.pdf?1446055191) is listed by PFS, not a NRTL, to UL 127, not on the list.

Answer (score 6):

The memo you've linked refers to the [Denver Building and Fire code](https://www.denvergov.org/content/dam/denvergov/Portals/696/documents/Denver_Building_Code/2016_Denver_Building_andFire_Code_Amendments.pdf) (the 2011 edition, not the current 2016 edition, but the section numbers still seem to match up), which in turn includes the [2015 International Fire Code](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IFC2015) as amended.  The "Listed" wording comes from Denver's amendments, while the definition comes from chapter 2 of the IFC:

> LISTED. Equipment, materials, products or services included in a list published by an organization acceptable to the fire code official and concerned with evaluation of products or services that maintains periodic inspection of production of listed equipment or materials or periodic evaluation of services and whose listing states either that the equipment, material, product or service meets identified standards or has been tested and found suitable for a specified purpose.

If Denver has a list of acceptable organizations, I've been unable to find it.

Answer (score 1):

"Listed" is a term of art referring to devices tested and approved by a Nationally Recognized Testing Laboratory. [This](https://www.osha.gov/dts/otpca/nrtl/nrtllist.html) is the list of recognized listers. [Here too](https://www.osha.gov/dts/otpca/nrtl/recgterm.html) is a list of organizations that are not recognized. You can start an organization by submitting an [application](https://www.osha.gov/dts/otpca/nrtl/appinfo.html) to OSHA. OSHA gets to say who is approved because of the [Occupational Safety and Health Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occupational_Safety_and_Health_Act_(United_States)). The requirements for becoming an NRTL are [here](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/29/1910.7).

Comment: "Listed" as used here is a legal term, defined in the 2015 International Fire Code.  The fact that it is *also* a term of art with a different meaning is irrelevant.

Comment: "Listed" is more general than that, not limited to fire codes, and has been around for much longer than 3 years. The fact that it is also defined in the 2015 International Fire Code is irrelevant.

Comment: The question refers to a memo from the Denver Fire Department.  The memo cites sections from the Denver Building and Fire Code, which includes by reference the International Fire Code.  The International Fire code gives a definition of "Listed".  As a general principle of law, the most specific definition of a word (in this case, the definition given in Chapter 2 of the IFC) overrides a more general definition.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested "Listed" refers to being successfully tested by one of the national testing labs, of which Underwriter's Laboratory is probably the best known. There are others (ETL being a common alternative).

One is free to start their own testing company, but whether or not it is recognized by anyone, including the City of Denver, is an entirely different matter. The good news is that most products for which a "listing" would be required either have one, or really shouldn't be used on a balcony. This last bit is the important part -- "UL / ETL Listing" really is about ensuring a product is designed with safety in mind.